# There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation (HDFS error)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

this error popped out after i tried to put a csv file in the folder ookla,does anyone have any idea why does this happened? I will really appreciate if someone can explain to me. I am quite new to hadoop.

```
 [hadoop_@master ~]$ hdfs dfs -put Ookla_ZTE.csv /ookla
 17/03/24 15:29:52 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
 org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /ookla/Ookla_ZTE.csv._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:725)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
put: File /ookla/Ookla_ZTE.csv._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

Comment: Your datanodes are not running. Check the datanode logs.

Comment: When i check the logs , it shows that it is running such as : hadoop-hadoop_-datanode-master.out.1,1436 Mar 27 08:50 hadoop-hadoop_-datanode-master.out.2 and so on, may I know is this correct? @franklinsijo

Comment: Not `.out` files, Look for `.log` files.

Comment: -rw-rw-r--.  1 hadoopuser hadoopuser 29058 Mar 27 16:00 hadoop-hadoopuser-datanode-master.log
-rw-rw-r--.  1 hadoopuser hadoopuser  1442 Mar 27 16:00 hadoop-hadoopuser-datanode-master.out
-rw-rw-r--.  1 hadoopuser hadoopuser 27625 Mar 27 16:03 hadoop-hadoopuser-namenode-master.log
-rw-rw-r--.  1 hadoopuser hadoopuser   721 Mar 27 16:00 hadoop-hadoopuser-namenode-master.out
-rw-rw-r--.  1 hadoopuser hadoopuser 21999 Mar 27 16:01 hadoop-hadoopuser-secondarynamenode-master.log
-rw-rw-r--.  1 hadoopuser hadoopuser   721 Mar 27 16:00 hadoop-hadoopuser-secondarynamenode-master.out

Comment: These are your log files, take the latest datanode log file `hadoop-hadoopuser-datanode-master.log` and check for `ERROR` in it.

Comment: I am kinda new to hadoop, if i may know what type of error that may show,because when i open the log file, it shows this :                                 2017-03-27 16:00:05,725 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = master.hadoop.lan/10.89.20.22
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.7.3

Comment: There is more to this file. Scroll to end of the file to view the error message.