# Error in datanode Hadoop 2.7.3 single node (pseudo-distributed mode)

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2.7.3

I am quite new to hadoop, and I've already respond to my previous question for this ,but the comment section is too short for me to show my log files. 
[This is my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993958/there-are-0-datanodes-running-and-no-nodes-are-excluded-in-this-operation-h) . Can anyone help me to find the error in this log file? I would highly appreciate it. Thank you.

```
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r baa91f7c6bc9cb92be5982de4719c1c8af91ccff; compiled by 'root' on 2016-08-18T01:41Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_121
************************************************************/
2017-03-27 16:14:50,262 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2017-03-27 16:14:51,049 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2017-03-27 16:14:51,131 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2017-03-27 16:14:51,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2017-03-27 16:14:51,134 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2017-03-27 16:14:51,139 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockScanner: Initialized block scanner with targetBytesPerSec 1048576
2017-03-27 16:14:51,142 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Configured hostname is master.hadoop.lan
2017-03-27 16:14:51,151 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting DataNode with maxLockedMemory = 0
2017-03-27 16:14:51,179 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Shutdown complete.
2017-03-27 16:14:51,180 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:50010] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:721)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:425)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.net.TcpPeerServer.<init>(TcpPeerServer.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initDataXceiver(DataNode.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:1111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2308)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2485)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2509)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:408)
    ... 10 more
  2017-03-27 16:14:51,184 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
  2017-03-27 16:14:51,186 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
 /************************************************************
```

Comment: Thanks @franklinsijo for your time, it works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error log, it looks like a process is already using the port `50010`.

> java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:50010]
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use

In most cases it is the `datanode` process itself which is not properly terminated.

Get the `pid` of the process using the port

```
netstat -ntpl | grep 50010

tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:50010 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN <pid>/java
```

Also Verify which process is using the port

```
ps -ef | grep <pid>
```

and `kill` the process

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Now that the port is free, try restarting the cluster.

If the process cannot be killed, change the port of datanode by adding this property to `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.address</name>
   <value>hostname:different_port</value>
</property>
```

Refer [Hadoop BindException](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException) for all possible causes of this `ERROR`.